# Error found when loading /home/(username)/.profile

Tags: bash, login

I'm getting an error upon login:

```
Error found when loading /home/(username)/.profile:
/home/(username)/.bashrc: line 1: /bin/bash:: No such file or directory
```

As a result the session will not be configured correctly.
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible.

I've checked other posts and no one seems to be getting this exact same issue.
I checked my .bashrc file, and this is what it says.

```bash
/bin/bash: line 1: q: command not found
#see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
#for examples

#If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

#don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
#See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

#append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

#for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

It doesn't seem to be causing any noticeable issues after login, other than showing the error message every time. Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is there an error message included in your `.bashrc` file?  Removing that first line should solve your issue. I don't even think this warrants a real answer as it almost amounts to a "typo".

Comment: that fist line in `.bashrc` is usually the comment `# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.` - but as with all comments, it doesn't even need to be there. You've clearly edited your .bashrc file and messed it up

Answer (score 0):

You must remove this line:

`/bin/bash: line 1: q: command not found`

In your error:

`/home/(username)/.profile: /home/(username)/.bashrc: line 1: /bin/bash::`

Notice the two `:` (this gave it away for me) this means it is trying to run `/bin/bash:` so it is actually trying to run that line.